# Failed to connect socket to 'var/run/libvirt/virtxend-sock': file or directory not found

Tags: ubuntu, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, xen, libvirt

I want to boot a physical installation of windows 10,so I need to run xen HVM version. Do u have a tutorial that I can follow ?

I'm trying to create a new connection inside virt-manager,with xen,on ubuntu 20.04 because I want to create a windows 10 guest where I will pass my graphic card,the RTX 2080 ti. These are the steps that I have already made :

1. I've already setup and configured everything to pass through my graphic card using qemu and kvm and it works.
2. I configured a little bit xen like this :

a) created this script :

```
!/bin/bash

if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then

echo "Require PCI devices in format: <domain>:<bus>:<slot>.<function>"

echo "Eg: $(basename $0) 0000:00:1b.0"

exit 1

fi

modprobe xen-pciback

for pcidev in $@; do

if [ -h /sys/bus/pci/devices/"$pcidev"/driver ]; then

echo "Unbinding $pcidev from" $(basename $(readlink /sys/bus/pci/devices/"$pcidev"/driver))

echo -n "$pcidev" > /sys/bus/pci/devices/"$pcidev"/driver/unbind

fi

echo "Binding $pcidev to pciback"

echo -n "$pcidev" > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/pciback/new_slot

echo -n "$pcidev" > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/pciback/bind

done
```

b) as soon as I run the script,I get this message :

```
Binding 0000:01:00.0 to pciback


confirmed by :


root@ziomario-I9:/home/ziomario/Scrivania/# xl pci-assignable-list

0000:01:00.0
```

it seems good,but when I try to create a new connection to xen using virt-manager,this is the error that I see :

[image: xen can't connect to libvirt xen]

I gave a look inside the xen.log file and this is what I see :

```
2020-06-21 17:26:05.207+0000: starting up libvirt version: 6.0.0, package: 0ubuntu8.1 (Christian Ehrhardt <christian.ehrhardt@canonical.com> Wed, 20 May 2020 06:59:57 +0200), qemu version: 4.2.0Debian 1:4.2-3ubuntu6.2, kernel: 5.4.0-38-generic, hostname: ziomario-I9

LC_ALL=C \

PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin \

HOME=/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/domain-1-xen \

XDG_DATA_HOME=/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/domain-1-xen/.local/share \

XDG_CACHE_HOME=/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/domain-1-xen/.cache \

XDG_CONFIG_HOME=/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/domain-1-xen/.config \

QEMU_AUDIO_DRV=spice \

/usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64 \

-name guest=xen,debug-threads=on \

-S \

-object secret,id=masterKey0,format=raw,file=/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/domain-1-xen/master-key.aes \

-machine pc-i440fx-focal,accel=kvm,usb=off,vmport=off,dump-guest-core=off \

-cpu Skylake-Client-IBRS,ss=on,vmx=on,hypervisor=on,tsc-adjust=on,clflushopt=on,umip=on,md-clear=on,stibp=on,arch-capabilities=on,ssbd=on,xsaves=on,pdpe1gb=on,ibpb=on,amd-ssbd=on,rdctl-no=on,ibrs-all=on,skip-l1dfl-vmentry=on,mds-no=on,hle=off,rtm=off \

-m 16000 \

-overcommit mem-lock=off \

-smp 14,sockets=14,cores=1,threads=1 \

-uuid b0f2acdc-8943-473a-8027-05d75596bc22 \

-no-user-config \

-nodefaults \

-chardev socket,id=charmonitor,fd=31,server,nowait \

-mon chardev=charmonitor,id=monitor,mode=control \

-rtc base=utc,driftfix=slew \

-global kvm-pit.lost_tick_policy=delay \

-no-hpet \

-no-shutdown \

-global PIIX4_PM.disable_s3=1 \

-global PIIX4_PM.disable_s4=1 \

-boot strict=on \

-device ich9-usb-ehci1,id=usb,bus=pci.0,addr=0x5.0x7 \

-device ich9-usb-uhci1,masterbus=usb.0,firstport=0,bus=pci.0,multifunction=on,addr=0x5 \

-device ich9-usb-uhci2,masterbus=usb.0,firstport=2,bus=pci.0,addr=0x5.0x1 \

-device ich9-usb-uhci3,masterbus=usb.0,firstport=4,bus=pci.0,addr=0x5.0x2 \

-device ahci,id=sata0,bus=pci.0,addr=0xc \

-device virtio-serial-pci,id=virtio-serial0,bus=pci.0,addr=0x6 \

-blockdev '{"driver":"file","filename":"/var/lib/libvirt/images/xen.qcow2","node-name":"libvirt-8-storage","auto-read-only":true,"discard":"unmap"}' \

-blockdev '{"node-name":"libvirt-8-format","read-only":false,"driver":"qcow2","file":"libvirt-8-storage","backing":null}' \

-device ide-hd,bus=ide.0,unit=0,drive=libvirt-8-format,id=ide0-0-0,bootindex=1 \

-blockdev '{"driver":"file","filename":"/home/ziomario/Scrivania/TooLinux/XPNG/xcp-ng-8.1.0-2.iso","node-name":"libvirt-7-storage","auto-read-only":true,"discard":"unmap"}' \

-blockdev '{"node-name":"libvirt-7-format","read-only":true,"driver":"raw","file":"libvirt-7-storage"}' \

-device ide-cd,bus=ide.0,unit=1,drive=libvirt-7-format,id=ide0-0-1,bootindex=2 \

-blockdev '{"driver":"host_device","filename":"/dev/sda","aio":"native","node-name":"libvirt-6-storage","cache":{"direct":true,"no-flush":false},"auto-read-only":true,"discard":"unmap"}' \

-blockdev '{"node-name":"libvirt-6-format","read-only":false,"cache":{"direct":true,"no-flush":false},"driver":"raw","file":"libvirt-6-storage"}' \

-device ide-hd,bus=sata0.0,drive=libvirt-6-format,id=sata0-0-0,write-cache=on \

-blockdev '{"driver":"host_device","filename":"/dev/sdb","aio":"native","node-name":"libvirt-5-storage","cache":{"direct":true,"no-flush":false},"auto-read-only":true,"discard":"unmap"}' \

-blockdev '{"node-name":"libvirt-5-format","read-only":false,"cache":{"direct":true,"no-flush":false},"driver":"raw","file":"libvirt-5-storage"}' \

-device ide-hd,bus=sata0.1,drive=libvirt-5-format,id=sata0-0-1,write-cache=on \

-blockdev '{"driver":"host_device","filename":"/dev/sdc","aio":"native","node-name":"libvirt-4-storage","cache":{"direct":true,"no-flush":false},"auto-read-only":true,"discard":"unmap"}' \

-blockdev '{"node-name":"libvirt-4-format","read-only":false,"cache":{"direct":true,"no-flush":false},"driver":"raw","file":"libvirt-4-storage"}' \

-device ide-hd,bus=sata0.2,drive=libvirt-4-format,id=sata0-0-2,write-cache=on \

-blockdev '{"driver":"host_device","filename":"/dev/sde","aio":"native","node-name":"libvirt-3-storage","cache":{"direct":true,"no-flush":false},"auto-read-only":true,"discard":"unmap"}' \

-blockdev '{"node-name":"libvirt-3-format","read-only":false,"cache":{"direct":true,"no-flush":false},"driver":"raw","file":"libvirt-3-storage"}' \

-device usb-storage,bus=usb.0,port=4,drive=libvirt-3-format,id=usb-disk3,removable=off,write-cache=on \

-blockdev '{"driver":"host_device","filename":"/dev/sdf","aio":"native","node-name":"libvirt-2-storage","cache":{"direct":true,"no-flush":false},"auto-read-only":true,"discard":"unmap"}' \

-blockdev '{"node-name":"libvirt-2-format","read-only":false,"cache":{"direct":true,"no-flush":false},"driver":"raw","file":"libvirt-2-storage"}' \

-device usb-storage,bus=usb.0,port=5,drive=libvirt-2-format,id=usb-disk4,removable=off,write-cache=on \

-blockdev '{"driver":"host_device","filename":"/dev/sdj","aio":"native","node-name":"libvirt-1-storage","cache":{"direct":true,"no-flush":false},"auto-read-only":true,"discard":"unmap"}' \

-blockdev '{"node-name":"libvirt-1-format","read-only":false,"cache":{"direct":true,"no-flush":false},"driver":"raw","file":"libvirt-1-storage"}' \

-device usb-storage,bus=usb.0,port=6,drive=libvirt-1-format,id=usb-disk5,removable=off,write-cache=on \

-netdev tap,fd=33,id=hostnet0 \

-device e1000,netdev=hostnet0,id=net0,mac=52:54:00:07:8b:8b,bus=pci.0,addr=0x3 \

-chardev pty,id=charserial0 \

-device isa-serial,chardev=charserial0,id=serial0 \

-chardev spicevmc,id=charchannel0,name=vdagent \

-device virtserialport,bus=virtio-serial0.0,nr=1,chardev=charchannel0,id=channel0,name=com.redhat.spice.0 \

-device usb-tablet,id=input0,bus=usb.0,port=1 \

-spice port=5900,addr=127.0.0.1,disable-ticketing,image-compression=off,seamless-migration=on \

-device qxl-vga,id=video0,ram_size=67108864,vram_size=67108864,vram64_size_mb=0,vgamem_mb=16,max_outputs=1,bus=pci.0,addr=0x2 \

-device intel-hda,id=sound0,bus=pci.0,addr=0x4 \

-device hda-duplex,id=sound0-codec0,bus=sound0.0,cad=0 \

-chardev spicevmc,id=charredir0,name=usbredir \

-device usb-redir,chardev=charredir0,id=redir0,bus=usb.0,port=2 \

-chardev spicevmc,id=charredir1,name=usbredir \

-device usb-redir,chardev=charredir1,id=redir1,bus=usb.0,port=3 \

-device vfio-pci,host=0000:01:00.0,id=hostdev0,bus=pci.0,addr=0x8 \

-device vfio-pci,host=0000:01:00.1,id=hostdev1,bus=pci.0,addr=0x9 \

-device vfio-pci,host=0000:01:00.2,id=hostdev2,bus=pci.0,addr=0xa \

-device vfio-pci,host=0000:01:00.3,id=hostdev3,bus=pci.0,addr=0xb \

-device virtio-balloon-pci,id=balloon0,bus=pci.0,addr=0x7 \

-sandbox on,obsolete=deny,elevateprivileges=deny,spawn=deny,resourcecontrol=deny \

-msg timestamp=on

char device redirected to /dev/pts/1 (label charserial0)

2020-06-21T17:26:13.135210Z qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(48FH).vmx-exit-load-perf-global-ctrl [bit 12]

2020-06-21T17:26:13.135362Z qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(490H).vmx-entry-load-perf-global-ctrl [bit 13]

2020-06-21T17:26:13.138807Z qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(48FH).vmx-exit-load-perf-global-ctrl [bit 12]

2020-06-21T17:26:13.138842Z qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(490H).vmx-entry-load-perf-global-ctrl [bit 13]

2020-06-21T17:26:13.141143Z qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(48FH).vmx-exit-load-perf-global-ctrl [bit 12]

2020-06-21T17:26:13.141177Z qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(490H).vmx-entry-load-perf-global-ctrl [bit 13]

2020-06-21T17:26:13.143389Z qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(48FH).vmx-exit-load-perf-global-ctrl [bit 12]

2020-06-21T17:26:13.143425Z qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(490H).vmx-entry-load-perf-global-ctrl [bit 13]

2020-06-21T17:26:13.145629Z qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(48FH).vmx-exit-load-perf-global-ctrl [bit 12]

2020-06-21T17:26:13.145664Z qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(490H).vmx-entry-load-perf-global-ctrl [bit 13]

2020-06-21T17:26:13.147876Z qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(48FH).vmx-exit-load-perf-global-ctrl [bit 12]

2020-06-21T17:26:13.147909Z qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(490H).vmx-entry-load-perf-global-ctrl [bit 13]

2020-06-21T17:26:13.150103Z qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(48FH).vmx-exit-load-perf-global-ctrl [bit 12]

2020-06-21T17:26:13.150134Z qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(490H).vmx-entry-load-perf-global-ctrl [bit 13]

2020-06-21T17:26:13.152365Z qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(48FH).vmx-exit-load-perf-global-ctrl [bit 12]

2020-06-21T17:26:13.152399Z qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(490H).vmx-entry-load-perf-global-ctrl [bit 13]

2020-06-21T17:26:13.154588Z qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(48FH).vmx-exit-load-perf-global-ctrl [bit 12]

2020-06-21T17:26:13.154621Z qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(490H).vmx-entry-load-perf-global-ctrl [bit 13]

2020-06-21T17:26:13.156741Z qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(48FH).vmx-exit-load-perf-global-ctrl [bit 12]

2020-06-21T17:26:13.156775Z qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(490H).vmx-entry-load-perf-global-ctrl [bit 13]

2020-06-21T17:26:13.158861Z qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(48FH).vmx-exit-load-perf-global-ctrl [bit 12]

2020-06-21T17:26:13.158892Z qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(490H).vmx-entry-load-perf-global-ctrl [bit 13]

2020-06-21T17:26:13.161141Z qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(48FH).vmx-exit-load-perf-global-ctrl [bit 12]

2020-06-21T17:26:13.161177Z qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(490H).vmx-entry-load-perf-global-ctrl [bit 13]

2020-06-21T17:26:13.163436Z qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(48FH).vmx-exit-load-perf-global-ctrl [bit 12]

2020-06-21T17:26:13.163473Z qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(490H).vmx-entry-load-perf-global-ctrl [bit 13]

2020-06-21T17:26:13.165680Z qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(48FH).vmx-exit-load-perf-global-ctrl [bit 12]

2020-06-21T17:26:13.165715Z qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(490H).vmx-entry-load-perf-global-ctrl [bit 13]

2020-06-21T19:53:06.375592Z qemu-system-x86_64: terminating on signal 15 from pid 2604 (/usr/sbin/libvirtd)

2020-06-21 19:53:08.387+0000: shutting down, reason=destroyed
```

I'm using libvirt with qemu + kvm where I have already setup a working vm with windows 10 and the passthrough.

I have installed apt install xen-hypervisor ;

root@ziomario-I9:/home/ziomario/Scrivania# ls /var/run/libvirt/virtxend-sock

ls: '/var/run/libvirt/virtxend-sock': File or directory not found ;

I have already booted the xen kernel :

```
root@ziomario-I9:/home/ziomario/Scrivania# sudo dmesg | grep Xen


[ 0.000000] Xen: [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000000009cfff] usable

[ 0.000000] Xen: [mem 0x000000000009d400-0x00000000000fffff] reserved

[ 0.000000] Xen: [mem 0x0000000000100000-0x000000002c318fff] usable

[ 0.000000] Xen: [mem 0x000000002c319000-0x000000002c319fff] ACPI NVS

[ 0.000000] Xen: [mem 0x000000002c31a000-0x000000002c31afff] reserved

[ 0.000000] Xen: [mem 0x000000002c31b000-0x00000000389d2fff] usable

[ 0.000000] Xen: [mem 0x00000000389d3000-0x0000000038e52fff] reserved

[ 0.000000] Xen: [mem 0x0000000038e53000-0x000000003900dfff] usable

[ 0.000000] Xen: [mem 0x000000003900e000-0x0000000039416fff] ACPI NVS

[ 0.000000] Xen: [mem 0x0000000039417000-0x0000000039efefff] reserved

[ 0.000000] Xen: [mem 0x0000000039eff000-0x0000000039efffff] usable

[ 0.000000] Xen: [mem 0x0000000039f00000-0x000000003f7fffff] reserved

[ 0.000000] Xen: [mem 0x00000000e0000000-0x00000000efffffff] reserved

[ 0.000000] Xen: [mem 0x00000000fe000000-0x00000000fe010fff] reserved

[ 0.000000] Xen: [mem 0x00000000fec00000-0x00000000fec00fff] reserved

[ 0.000000] Xen: [mem 0x00000000fed90000-0x00000000fed91fff] reserved

[ 0.000000] Xen: [mem 0x00000000fee00000-0x00000000feefffff] reserved

[ 0.000000] Xen: [mem 0x00000000ff000000-0x00000000ffffffff] reserved

[ 0.000000] Xen: [mem 0x0000000100000000-0x00000008be7fffff] usable

[ 0.000000] Hypervisor detected: Xen PV

[ 2.971846] Setting APIC routing to Xen PV.

[ 3.650154] Booting paravirtualized kernel on Xen

[ 3.650155] Xen version: 4.11.4-pre (preserve-AD)

[ 3.764547] Xen: using vcpuop timer interface

[ 3.764550] installing Xen timer for CPU 0

[ 3.767598] installing Xen timer for CPU 1

[ 3.767805] installing Xen timer for CPU 2

[ 3.768672] installing Xen timer for CPU 3

[ 3.768875] installing Xen timer for CPU 4

[ 3.768875] installing Xen timer for CPU 5

[ 3.768875] installing Xen timer for CPU 6

[ 3.768875] installing Xen timer for CPU 7

[ 3.768875] installing Xen timer for CPU 8

[ 3.768875] installing Xen timer for CPU 9

[ 3.768875] installing Xen timer for CPU 10

[ 3.768875] installing Xen timer for CPU 11

[ 3.768875] installing Xen timer for CPU 12

[ 3.768875] installing Xen timer for CPU 13

[ 3.768875] installing Xen timer for CPU 14

[ 3.768875] installing Xen timer for CPU 15

[ 4.887481] xen_mcelog: /dev/mcelog registered by Xen

[ 4.889312] xen_acpi_processor: Uploading Xen processor PM info

[ 4.896240] xen_netfront: Initialising Xen virtual ethernet driver
```